# Looking for a Regex to get SccTeamFoundationServer value from .sln file

Tags: c#, regex, tfs

I am looking tor a Regex for C# to get SccTeamFoundationServer value from .sln file.
Maybe someone has come across such need and found a solution. Could you help?

File:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 10.00
# Visual Studio 2008
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "WebApplication", "WebApplication\WebApplication.csproj", "{AE0F6C02-1C8D-426D-AFA0-C07A52E6112F}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "ConsoleApplication", "ConsoleApplication\ConsoleApplication.csproj", "{2BD82C34-CF50-4559-A3CD-F85ACD657292}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
        SccNumberOfProjects = 3
        SccEnterpriseProvider = {4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}
        SccTeamFoundationServer = http://ServerName:8080/
        SccLocalPath0 = .
        SccProjectUniqueName1 = ConsoleApplication\\ConsoleApplication.csproj
        SccProjectName1 = ConsoleApplication
        SccLocalPath1 = ConsoleApplication
        SccProjectUniqueName2 = WebApplication\\WebApplication.csproj
        SccProjectName2 = WebApplication
        SccLocalPath2 = WebApplication
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {AE0F6C02-1C8D-426D-AFA0-C07A52E6112F}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {AE0F6C02-1C8D-426D-AFA0-C07A52E6112F}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {AE0F6C02-1C8D-426D-AFA0-C07A52E6112F}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {AE0F6C02-1C8D-426D-AFA0-C07A52E6112F}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {2BD82C34-CF50-4559-A3CD-F85ACD657292}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {2BD82C34-CF50-4559-A3CD-F85ACD657292}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {2BD82C34-CF50-4559-A3CD-F85ACD657292}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {2BD82C34-CF50-4559-A3CD-F85ACD657292}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: it would be much easier if you give example of file, because people might be familiar with regexp but not with .sln format

Comment: Otherwise try getting Expresso - http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm. It's a very helpful tool for creating regular expressions. You caneven paste the contents of your sln file into the app to see that it extracts the correct value.

Comment: @jjrdk Or a similar online tool: http://txt2re.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823259/tfs-moving-to-a-new-server-how-to-update-solutions-with-new-server-info) and a bit of guesswork, the following might do the trick:

```
\bSccTeamFoundationServer\s*=\s*(['"]?)([^\1\n]*)\1
```

It allows for optional single/double quotes and uses backreferences to make sure the quotes used on either end match. It doesn't handle escaped quotes.

Comment: Thank you, but it gets me all text after "SccTeamFoundationServer = http://ServerName:8080/"

Comment: @Arthur Then put a `\n` in the grouped character class. See edit.

Comment: Could you paste a full Regex?

Answer (score 0):

If I use this

(SccTeamFoundationServer\s*=\s*(.*))

The TFS server address will be capture group 2. The entire line is capture group 1. You can add names to the capture groups if you wish to make it easier for you to extract them.

Comment: Thank you, but it gets me all text after "SccTeamFoundationServer = ServerName:8080/" as well.